# Loading a capacitor in an RC circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, electrical-resistance

I have an RC circuit to which I am going to apply voltages of 5V every 100ns. So every 100ns, the capacitor will change its "state" from charging up to uncharging.

I have been trying to find the a formula that tells you what is the voltage in function of time V(t) of a capacitor *that has already some initial voltage*.

I know it is some variation from the V(t) = Vin*(1-e....) but i can't find it.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the applied voltage and the circuit? Does the voltage go from 5V to 0V? Is the resistor in series with the voltage source or parallel with the capacitor? Please clarify. Then write an expression for the current - which is just change in voltage across the resistor, divided by the resistance. The voltage across the capacitor goes up or down depending on the direction of that current, according to an equation you should know. Write all that into the question - and if you are still stuck, you might get further help.

Comment: @Ruben This is really an engineering problem and is therefore off-topic.  Please consider posting in [electronics.se].

Answer (score 1):

You want $\frac {dV}{dt}=\frac IC$, where $I$ is the current into the capacitor and $C$ is the capacitance.  This is independent of the state of charge of the capacitor.  The $I$ will vary depending on the state of charge.  If you are charging from $5$ volts through a resistance $R$, the current will be $\frac {5-V}R$.  Then when the input voltage goes to zero, you will discharge with a current $\frac VR$.  In both cases you will have an exponential decay to the supply voltage with time constant $RC$